# Filling Word template with OpenXML - Bookmarks or ContentControls

Tags: ms-word, openxml, bookmarks

I've an application that automatically fills MS Word templates (.dotx) written using COM and Word object model. There are some Bookmarks in the template, that are filled programmatically.
Now I'm migrating to OpenXML.
Could you please explain me what should I prefer using OpenXML - Bookmarks or Content Controls and why?

Comment: Do you need repeating data (eg rows of a table), and conditional inclusion? If so, you'll need to decide how to do that. For content controls, http://www.opendope.org is one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content controls are significantly more resistant to overwriting during document editing. You can use either one with OpenXML without additional complications.

Answer (score 1):

WordDocumentGenerator is an utility to generate Word documents from templates using Visual Studio 2010 and Open XML 2.0 SDK. The code is available for download at http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com/. Content controls are used in templates. A lot of samples are provided for document generation which will show how functional and flexible content controls are.